# Any way of doing this iterator filter with boost MPL or similar

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

Essentially I have a couple of situations where I'm using `boost::filter_iterator` to filter an iterator for some conditions. There's a situation where I want to filter for 2 conditions simultaneously and we have some pre-existing code for this already but I'd like to know if there's a idiomatic way to do this with boost or the standard library:

```
    /*! TODO: Surely there should be something in std/boost to achieve this??? */
    /*! Filter for things that satisfy F1 and F2 */
    template <
        typename F1,
        typename F2,
        typename ArgT
    >
    struct filter_and
    {
        F1 f1;
        F2 f2;

        filter_and(F1 _f1, F2 _f2): f1(_f1), f2(_f2)
        {}

        inline bool operator() (ArgT const& arg) const
        {
            return f1(arg) && f2(arg);
        }
    };
```

If a solution requires c++11 that should be fine as long as the latest MSVC can handle it.

Comment: Why not just stacking two filter iterators over each other?

Comment: @ipc, I actually hadn't thought of doing that, perhaps that's a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `make_filter_iterator( it, [=](value_type const& v) { return f1(v) && f2(v); } );`

For something fancier...

```
bool and_in_order() { return true; }
template<typename F0, typename Funcs...>
bool and_in_order( F0&& f0, Funcs&&... funcs ) {
  return f0() && and_in_order(funcs...);
}

template<typename... Funcs>
struct and_unary_functors {
  std::tuple<Funcs...> funcs;
  template<typename Arg, typename seq=typename make_seq<sizeof...(Funcs)>::type>
  bool operator()(Arg&& arg) const;

  template<typename Arg, int...s>
  bool operator()<Arg, seq<s...>>(Arg&& arg) const {
    return and_in_order( [&](){ return get<s>(funcs)(arg); }... );
  }
};

template<typename... Funcs>
and_unary_functors<Funcs> make_and_unary( Funcs const&... funcs ) {
  return {std::make_tuple(funcs...)};
};

auto filter_it = make_filter_iterator( base_iterator, make_and_unary( f1, f2, f3, f4 ) );
```

or something silly like that.